# redirect PHP login dynamically

Tags: php, session, redirect, dynamic, authentication

With existing codes handed in to me, I would need to redirect logins in PHP automatically or dynamically based on the source calling the login.php file. Let me enumerate first the web pages involved:

1. A dashboard page, like view_list.php, which is the homepage after user is logged in
2. A check_session.php page which checks if the user is logged in. Otherwise, it redirects the user using below:

   ```
   if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) 
   { 
          $url = "http://sample.com/login.php"; 
          header("location:$url");
   }
   ```
3. A login.php page, which accepts inputs of username and password, and if successfully authenticated, redirects back to the dashboard page

Now, apart from the dashboard page in item #1, there are lots of other pages which check user session, through check_session.php. What I would want is that coming from any of those pages, the user will be redirected to login.php (if session indicated not logged in), and the login.php will redirect the user back to the original page accessed before login.php. The redirection is currently being done using header("location:$url"). The solution I have in mind is to define a GET parameter in both the check_session.php and login.php and which will be appended to the URL location. Hence, the flow of GET parameters will be  **view_list.php >> check_session.php >> login.php** .

Since there are at least 3 pages involved, I am thinking if this is the only feasible solution, given the existing codes. Currently, whatever the starting page or landing page (other pages are directly accessed via URL), all of them will have the same page to be redirected to, hard-coded in login.php. The codes are written in native PHP. Would highly appreciate your inputs. Thanks!

Comment: I missed a fourth web page. If the user is not logged in based on **check_session.php**, it is redirected as header to the **login.php** page, which is a form containing inputs for username and password. The form has an action which redirects to **check_login.php**, which then authenticates the username and password, and then redirects back to the first web page, say **view_list.php**. I think it's the form in login.php that complicates it.

Answer (score 1):

do something like this for your common header:

```
session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['loggedin']) {
   $_SESSION['return_url'] = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
   header("Location: login.php");
   exit();
}
```

Basically save the url of the current page in the session, then redirect to the login page. Then in the login handler:

```
session_start();
... process login ...
if(login_successful()) {
   $return_to = $_SESSION['return_url'];
   $_SESSION['return_url'] = null; // clear it, just in case.
   header("Location: $return_to");
}
```

Comment: I missed a fourth web page. If the user is not logged in based on **check_session.php**, it is redirected as header to the **login.php** page, which is a form containing input fields for username and password. The form has an action which redirects to **check_login.php**, which then authenticates the username and password, and then redirects back to the first web page, say **view_list.php**. I think it's the form in login.php that complicates it.

Comment: thanks for the solution. I got that working for me. However, I had to add $_GET and $_POST variables since there is a form involved for login.php. Hence, here is my implementation: **view_list.php** defining the return url gets redirected to common header **check_session.php**, having the return url being passed as a GET as header to **login.php**, which stores it as a hidden input, and is called via $_POST to **check_login.php**, and the received $_POST value is now passed on to the URL and appended. Please advise if this is the most feasible implementation. Thanks!